# How to create tuples from a single list with alpha-numeric chacters?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, zip, tuples

I have the following list with 2 elements:

```
['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
```

I need to make a list or zip file such that each alphabet corresponds to its number further in the list. For example in list[0] the list/zip should read

```
{"A":"6", "G":"6", "C":"35","T":"25","T":"10"}
```

Can I make a list of such lists/zips that stores the corresponding vales for list[0], list[1],...list[n]?

Note: The alphabets can only be A,G,C or T, and the numbers can take anyvalue

Edit 1: Previously, I thought I could use a dictionary. But several members pointed out that this cannot be done. So I just want to make a list or zip or anything else recommended to pair the Alphabet element to its corresponding number.

Comment: There are 3 `G`s in the second string, how would you handle this in the dictionary?

Comment: And `{"A":"6", "G":"6", "C":"35","T":"25","T":"10"}` has multiple `T` keys; not valid

Comment: You can't have a dictionary with multiple keys being the same ("T").  You can have the key "T" have multiple values

Comment: As already pointed out, you cannot have dupe keys so your expected output is not possible. You need to edit the question to address that,.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye  and everyone: Thanks for pointing it out. I have amended the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tuples splitting once to get the pairs, then split the second element of each pair,  *zip* together:

```
l  =['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']

pairs =  [zip(a,b.split()) for a,b in (sub.split(None,1) for sub in l]
```

Which would give you:

```
[[('A', '6'), ('G', '6'), ('C', '35'), ('T', '25'), ('T', '10')], [('A', '7'), ('G', '7'), ('G', '28'), ('G', '29'), ('T', '2')]]
```

Of using a for loop with *list.append:*

```
l  = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
out = []
for a,b in (sub.split(None,1) for sub in l ):
    out.append(zip(a,b))
```

If you want to convert any letter to `Z` where the digit is < 10, you just need another loop where we check the digit in each pairing:

```
pairs = [[("Z", i ) if int(i) < 10 else (c, i) for c,i in zip(a, b.split())] 
         for a,b in (sub.split(None, 1) for sub in l)]
print(pairs)
```

Which would give you:

```
[[('Z', '6'), ('Z', '6'), ('C', '35'), ('T', '25'), ('T', '10')], [('Z', '7'), ('Z', '7'), ('G', '28'), ('G', '29'), ('Z', '2')]]
```

To  break it into a regular loop:

```
pairs = []
for a, b in (sub.split(None, 1) for sub in l):
    pairs.append([("Z", i) if int(i) < 10 else (c, i) for c, i in zip(a, b.split())])
print(pairs)
```

`[("Z", i) if int(i) < 10 else (c, i) for c, i in zip(a, b.split())]` sets the letter to `Z` if the corresponding digit `i` is `< 10` or else we just leave the letter as is.

if you want to get back to the original pairs after you just need to [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) with *zip*:

```
In [13]: l = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']

In [14]: pairs = [[("Z", i) if int(i) < 10 else (c, i) for c, i in zip(a, b.split())] for a, b in
   ....:          (sub.split(None, 1) for sub in l)]

In [15]: pairs
Out[15]: 
[[('Z', '6'), ('Z', '6'), ('C', '35'), ('T', '25'), ('T', '10')],
 [('Z', '7'), ('Z', '7'), ('G', '28'), ('G', '29'), ('Z', '2')]]

In [16]: unzipped = [["".join(a), " ".join(b)] for a, b in (zip(*tup) for tup in pairs)]

In [17]: unzipped
Out[17]: [['ZZCTT', '6 6 35 25 10'], ['ZZGGZ', '7 7 28 29 2']]
```

`zip(*...)` will give you the original elements back into a tuple of their own, we then just need to join the strings back together. If you wanted to get back to the total original state you could just join again:

```
In[18][ " ".join(["".join(a), " ".join(b)]) for a, b in (zip(*tup) for tup in pairs) ]
Out[19]: ['ZZCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'ZZGGZ 7 7 28 29 2']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I need the two elements in the list AGCTT and AGGGT (and about 10 others) to be stored separately. Also, in this method can I access the numbers and alphabets separately?  For example, for alphabets corresponding to value less than 10, I want to replace the alphabets with "Z"

Comment: How do you mean stored separately? I edited to remove the flattening if that is what you mean.

Comment: I need: [[('A', '6'), ('G', '6'), ('C', '35'), ('T', '25'), ('T', '10')], [('A', '7'), ('G', '7'), ('G', '28'), ('G', '29'), ('T', '2')]]

Comment: And I should be able to write a further code saying for all alphabets where value <10; convert alphabet to "Z"

Comment: @Ash1234, that is what the code is doing now,  so you want T to become Z?

Comment: I apologize. You were perfectly correct the first time. But does this work as a list? For example, I should be able to write a further code saying for all alphabets where value <10; convert alphabet to "Z". So can i write for loops for these?

Comment: I think I should technically be asking this as a separate question. I will do that

Comment: Thanks a LOT! If I can trouble you for one another syntax. If I want to now  unzip such that I have all the alphabets together again..ZZCTT, is there a unzip function I can look up?

Comment: @Ash1234, unzipping is transposing, see the link in the answer for a good explanation.

Comment: @Padriac. I had a follow up question. If I had  a input sequence                                                       `>qrst`
`A10`
`>qqqq`
`A2`                                                                                                                                                How can I still use the same code to split the alpha numeric? Can I accommodate both `['A 10','A 2']` and `['A10','A2']` types of input file in the same line of code?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider using tuples to pair the items, then this works:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> lst = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
>>> new_lst = [list(zip(sub[0], sub[1:])) for sub in [i.split() for i in lst]]
>>> pprint(new_lst)
[[('A', '6'), ('G', '6'), ('C', '35'), ('T', '25'), ('T', '10')],
 [('A', '7'), ('G', '7'), ('G', '28'), ('G', '29'), ('T', '2')]]
```

1. `[i.split() for i in lst]`: An initial split on the string.
2. `zip(sub[0], sub[1:]))`: Zip lists of alphabets and list of numbers

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But does this work as a list? For example, I should be able to write a further code saying for all alphabets where value <10; convert alphabet to "Z". So can i write for loops for these

Comment: @PadraicCunningham My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through list > iterate through items (alpha numeric) of the list and construct list of characters and numbers > and then construct list of tuple.

```
alphanum = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
list_of_tuple = []

for s in alphanum:
   ints = []
   chars = []
   for i in s.split():
      if i.isdigit():
         ints.append(i)
      else:
         chars.append(i)

   new_tuple = []
   for (n, item) in enumerate(list(chars[0])):
       new_tuple.append((item, ints[n]))
   list_of_tuple.append(new_tuple)

print list_of_tuple
```

Answer (score -1):

This code would work, assuming the elements in the list are correctly formed.
This means the number of letters and numbers must match!

And it will overwrite the value if the key already exists.

```
list = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
dictionary = {}

for line in list:
    split_line = line.split()
    letters = split_line[0]
    iterator = 1
    for letter in letters:
        dictionary[letter] = split_line[iterator]
        iterator += 1

print dictionary
```

This modified one will check if the key exists and add it to a list with that key:

```
list = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
dictionary = {}

for line in list:
    split_line = line.split()
    letters = split_line[0]
    iterator = 1
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[letter].append(split_line[iterator])
        else:
            dictionary[letter] = [split_line[iterator]]

        iterator += 1

print dictionary
```

Comment: This should not be down-voted. The original question was flawed to begin with, and unsolvable. The OP wanted to create a dictionary where one key maps to 2 values.

Comment: Thank you, you can up-vote it if you think this is what the user actually wanted.