# How to rewrite the following zip code in nested for and if loops?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

List l has the following elements

```
l = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
```

List l was split into pairs using tuples, such that every alphabet corresponded as A:6, G:6, C:35 ..etc
If a value for less than 10, then the alphabets were converted to Z.
The following is the code:

```
pairs = []
for a, b in (sub.split(None, 1) for sub in l):
    pairs.append([("Z", i) if int(i) < 10 else (c, i) for c, i in zip(a,b.split())])
print(pairs)
```

How can one code the same thing using nested for and if loops? (I need to do this exercise to help understand coding in Python better)

Here is my attempt:

```
pairs =[]
for a, b in (sub.split(None, 1) #What is sub.split(None,1)
    for sub in l: 
        if int(i) < 10:
            pairs.append("Z",i)
        else:
            pairs.append(c,i)
print pairs
```

Note 1: If someone could help me frame the question better- specific to the questions, please do suggest changes

The above question and code (credits: P. Cunningham) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39441797/6820344)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse engineer the code, usually working on the python console is the best way to proceed. So, I would start taking the different statements apart one by one and see what each does. Now, there will probably be many different ways to explain/rewrite that code, so mine will be one that hopefully will help you understand the process.

Your code is good, but there is one problem and one discrepancy to the final desired output.

1. The problem is at the first loop: you should swap the `for a, b` with the `for sub in l` line, because this should give you an error about `sub` not being defined or so.
2. The discrepancy is that `pairs` is a list of lists, and instead you are trying to append a tuple. I say "try" because the statement is invalid and should be written as `pairs.append(("Z",i))` for example. But still misses the subtle `list` which is defined in the original code. In fact there you have a `pairs.append([])`, and the full logic inside creates what is called a `list comprehension`.

Nevertheless, very good work from your part.

The final "new code" looks like below and you can see it in action at: https://eval.in/639908

```
l = ['AGCTT 6 6 35 25 10', 'AGGGT 7 7 28 29 2']
pairs = []
# for each element in the list
for sub in l:   
    # we will create a new empty list
    new_list = []

    # split 'sub' into the string and the numbers parts
    a, b = sub.split(None, 1)   

    # further, split the numbers into a list
    numbers = b.split()

    # now using positional index, we will...
    for x in range(len(a)):
        # ... create a new tuple taking one character from string 
        # 'a' and one number from list 'numbers'
        new_tuple = ( a[x], numbers[x] )

        # if the value is less than 10, then...
        if int(numbers[x]) < 10:
            # ... let's just put "Z" 
            new_tuple = ("Z", numbers[x])   

        # append this to the temporary list
        new_list.append(new_tuple)    

    # once the sequence is complete, add it to the main list
    pairs.append(new_list)   

# When it's all done, print the list
print pairs
```

Comment: Hi Sal, Thanks a lot for this. I modified my code. But I find that ___ does not loop over.

Comment: Hi Sal, Thanks a lot for this. I modified my code with comments. I find that it does not loop over all the elements. Here is the code: https://eval.in/640732, I have marked where the trouble is

Comment: You never update `sequence`. Your code is very confusing :-) Take this as a constructive criticism. There's too many variables, and your loops are intermixed too much. Since it's a learning exercise, try to simplify/streamline your approach.

Comment: I don't understand, where I have to update my sequence? I don't make any changes to my sequnce. Its only thw qualities I make changes to.    No, thank you for letting me know, I appreciate it :). I am new user, so will defintely try to improve as I move along

Comment: We are all here to learn. I made a new version with more comments here: https://eval.in/640800
You will see that "sequence" is stuck at the last element in your loops.

Comment: Thanks. I understand where I have to place append now :)